# How to link to anchors from within an accordion

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, accordion

I have an accordion that has a lot of information in it and would like to be able to link to areas lower in the accordion. But when I create the anchor links and link to them they don't work. I just stay at the top of the accordion.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What accordion are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure. We have an solution that we've been using and that we've customized to work with SharePoint for a few years now. But we never had to create an anchor in an accordion and link to it from within that same accordion. 
I understand people most of the time want to link from another page to something within an accordion on a different page and have the accordion open up but in our case, you're already in the accordion. I set up the anchor and link to it but it doesn't jump to the anchor when I click on it. Thanks for any help!